# C# Crawler Moving single thread WebClient call to multi threading

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, web-crawler

We currently have a web crawler for our clients that do not have the ability to provide us with an xml file.  The list is building so I need to have a more efficient way to crawl these sites.  The logic of the crawler is simply:

```
Pass in www.example.com/widgets
Store the html and pass it to crawler function

crawl widgets page 1
 IF widgets page 1 is the end of their product list
   stop
 else 
   go to widgets page 2
```

This repeats for every site in the queue.  As you can see, if Site 1 has 5000 products, Site 2 cannot proceed until it is done.  What would be the best way to multi thread this so that i can limit how many request i make to each site, but grab multiple sites at one time?  I tried Parallel.ForEach but the result was very sporadic and unpredictable.  Currently we handle this by having "groups" of stores fire off and the same time using Windows Task Manager. here is some example code:

```
foreach(site in ListofSites)
{
  int page = 1;
  bool continue_crawling = true;
  while(continue_crawling)
  {
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    var htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
    htmlWeb.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36";
    doc = htmlWeb.Load(URL + page);
    string html = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
    continue_crawling = ParseFile(html);
    page++;
  }
}

private bool Parse(string html)
{
  //parse the file and see if we have enough data
 return endofproduct;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to hit the same site with multiple requests at once, or just do each site in a single thread (but visit more than one site at once)?

Comment: I want to limit my request to each site so that i do not overwhelm them.  If i have multiple request to each site I would need a way to stop other threads once one thread finds the ends of their list of products.  

Whatever overall is the most efficient is what we are going for.  A combination of both is even an option.  Correct data is the most important part.  Customers will be irate if our crawler misses a page of their products.

Answer (score 1):

All C# HTTP requests will go through the [`ServicePoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the request URL domain. The ServicePoint will inherit the [`ConnectionLimit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint.connectionlimit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from the [`ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The default value is 2, in accordance with the 'good clients practice' of [RFC2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt):

> A single-user client SHOULD NOT maintain more than 2 connections with any server or proxy.

What all that translates to is that launching 1 gazzilion HTTP requests to URLs in the same domain will only send at most 2 HTTP request, and another one will not start unless one finishes. To achieve higher concurrency you need to increase the ServicePoint connection limit for the domain of interest. Doing concurrent IO using threads (including PTL) is rather primitive, but should work if you fix the limitation. Doing async IO would be preferable, of course.

Comment: Would the fact that I have to know when I hit the product list end make this impossible? If I sent out 4 request to s site and got back pages 1-4, but the end of product was page 2.  I then would have to notify all the other threads of this site to stop after their current read.

Comment: You should know what you crawl... Why askbforbinvalid url to start with, you shoul be following a link.

Comment: There are a lot of scenarios where this is not possible.  The url may not be forbidden  For example, a company may have widgets a,b, and c all mixed together.  We may just need a so we stop our crawler as soon as the first b shows up.  Another example would be they only one products released in the past 6 months to be passed to us.  We sort by release date, then crawl till we hit 7 months at which point we have to stop our crawler there.

Comment: If you do opportunistic requests then you can cancel them, but you cannot know whether they have already started making the HTTP request or not. None the less, this is orthogonal to your question. My explanation shows how ` i can limit how many request i make to each site, but grab multiple sites at one time` is already built-in into the .Net Framework. the ServicePoint control the throtling, and they also explain your observations vis-a-vis the TPL use.